# Postgresql - Unable to find source code for function called by trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a trigger that runs on insert or update of a table but for the life of me, I can't find the source for that function... where should I be looking?

The SQL for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF search_data
    ON public.mytable
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION tsvector_update_trigger('search_vector', 'pg_catalog.english', 'search_data');
```

How do I get the source for the tsvector_update_trigger function? I'm looking in pgadmin right now and can't seem to find it but can also use psql.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: That's a [built-in](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-trigger.html) trigger function. You need to go through the Postgres source code to see the source of that function

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/tsvector_op.c#L93

Comment: I guess that explains why I can't find it :D